# Which would you prefer? SVG, HTML5 or regen'd-PNG for graphs & charts?

Tags: image, html, png, svg, scaling

I'm developing a new site that graphs some operational metrics.  As such about a dozen charts/graphs will be displayed on the site.  I want to be able to have them dynamically scale down (within reason) based upon the size of the browser.

I'm debating the pros/cons of generating these as one of these options:

1. **SVG**.  Great for scaling but may have limited support,
2. **HTML5**.  Clearly a great choice for the future and for FF customers, IE?
3. **PNG**.  This would
   require that I regenerate the PNG
   based upon the size of the DIV &c.

Which is the preferable option?  I'm leaning towards PNG just for ubiquitous support, but would like to have client-side scaling.  What is the best solution given the state of affairs of SVG and HTML5 canvas support in browsers?

Comment: 4. Flash. Would be cross-browser and be very fast/responsive. Plus you can code some fancy effects/interactions.

Comment: Secured environment.  No flash option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do worse than explore a new charting library:
http://g.raphaeljs.com/

You won't believe it at first.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer SVG over HTML5 canvas or PNG for charts. Canvas and PNG zoom as bitmaps in Firefox. (Canvas provides a vector API, but it's a drawable bitmaps surface--not a vector store.) SVG zooms as vector graphics in Firefox.

I ofter run with the view zoomed, so I appreciate real vector zooming.

(Canvas makes sense for games that can't handle the perf hit of retained mode graphics.)

Comment: I may need to start another question, but how would SVG dynamically scale in say a resized DIV?

Comment: In browsers that don't have full-page zoom and have only text zoom, you need to wrap the SVG element in an em-sized div and make the SVG box size to 100% of the containing div. My concern above was having vector zooming of the chart with the full-page zoom in Firefox >= 3.5, and to make that work, the em/div trick isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use [SVG anywhere](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/)

Comment: Secured environment. No flash option.

Answer (score 3):

SVG is supported by all modern browsers.
Canvas is supported by all modern browser.
Internet Explorer supports neither.
A partial API for SVG, with fallback mechanism for IE exists in Raphaël (raphaeljs.com)
A partial Canvas-implementation for IE exists in [ExCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/)

I'd say say its not a question of "Canvas or SVG", but what high-level library exists that best covers your needs.

Comment: Well, I'll be employing gnuplot which can produce any of the above for the most part with a flick of the output terminal switch.  I should mention that this needs to be without client plug-in, I'll need to read more as to this ExCanvas.

Answer (score 2):

The best option would be SVG or HTML5 that will fall back on PNG if the others aren't available.

Comment: An option is to generate PNG/JPGs from the SVG files serverside for the clients that don't support SVG.

Comment: If the <object> tag is used however, then one could default a PNG request inside should the SVG not be requested...might be best.

Answer (score 0):

[ExplorerCanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) brings `<canvas>` support to IE. So, it would be an amalgamation of 1 & 2. The benefit would be that (a) as more browsers add support for `<canvas>`, you would automatically get the benefits of already supporting it and (b) you would get scaling with browser size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVG with a png fallback just using CSS as it is described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13575068/418711