# SVG/PNG extension switch

Tags: php, javascript, svg, png, modernizr

Is there a way to use SVG images on my site and if browsers/devices do not support it, switch the extension to png? Is there a better way to do this?

Note: I am using the `<img>` tag and Modernizr.

Here is my code that spits out the images dynamically.

```
<?php $attachments = attachments_get_attachments(); ?>
        <?php if( function_exists( 'attachments_get_attachments' ) ) {
        $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
        $total_attachments = count( $attachments ); if( $total_attachments ) : ?><?php for( $i=0; $i<$total_attachments; $i++ ) : ?>
<img src="<?php echo $attachments[$i]['location']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $attachments[$i]['title']; ?>" class="full" />
<?php endfor; ?><?php endif; ?><?php } ?>
```

Outputs the following:
`<img src="http://mysiteurl.net/image.png" alt="Image Title"  class="full wp-image-287" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could test if `svg` is supported, and if not loop through your image tags and set their src path to `.png`. This example hasn't been tested, but it may be a step in the right direction.

```
if(!Modernizr.svg){
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    var src = images[i].src.split(".");
    images[i].src = src[0] + ".png";
  }
}
```

If jQuery is an option, then something like this may be possible:

```
if(!Modernizr.svg){
  $("img").each(function(){
    var src = this.src.split(".");
    this.src = src[0] + ".png";
  });
}
```

**EDIT**

You may also consider looking into [Modernizr-Server](https://github.com/jamesgpearce/modernizr-server). This way you can test for svg while you're looping through the images and append the appropriate extension.

```
if ($modernizr->svg) {
    ...
} elseif ($modernizr->canvas) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: jQuery is an option however, I would prefer a method that loads the image quite quickly.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code on how you're loading in the `img`s? Mainly, are they dynamically being added to the DOM as the page loads or are they static html?

Comment: I am using PHP to load the images in. I edited my code above.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton, I've updated my answer. In order to do that testing server-side, use Modernizr-Server. Other than that, trying to do this client side would require the javascript to wait until the DOM is ready and then loop through each `svg` image and change them to `png`

Comment: Thanks, Chase. I'm going to look at all these options and will accept as soon as possible.

Comment: @Duopixel That seems to just detect browsers. I would need it to detect devices too as certain Android tablets don't support SVG.

Comment: @Chase His suggestion probably won't work. See comment above.

Comment: I believe checking server-side would be the best option for you given what you've stated in this post. Since you're familiar with Modernizr (and php), I would highly suggest that route. If I come up with anything else that will work for you then I'll definitely let you know.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton no, there's no browser sniffing going on. `return document.createElementNS && document.createElementNS( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg").createSVGRect;` returns false if the browser is unable to handle SVG.

Answer (score 3):

This is working, filtering only svg file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    if(!Modernizr.svg){
      jQuery("img").each(function(){
        var src = this.src;
        if( src.match(/svg$/) ){
            // Replace "svg" by "png"
            this.src = src.slice(0,-3) + 'png'
        }           
      });
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a CSS-ony solution for SVG with fallback as described in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13575068/418711